# localStorage getItem showing null result after reloading

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to store Id from url but
Whenever I reload the page I got localStorage value - none

How the code works-
If the url is https://www.theseconds.xyz?id=demo
Then I got Id value that is demo
But when I refresh Page I am getting id value = null

I want store Id value such that if the id value is null then user must redirect to previous id value only and if the url got new id value then user must redirect to new id value.

This is my code

```
<p id="demo"></p>

const queryString = window.location.search;
const Urlparams =  new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const ids = Urlparams.get('id');
localStorage.setItem("name", ids);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('name');

// For hide url Id after getting value
if(document.URL.indexOf("/?id=")>= 0){
window.history.pushState('new','title','?m=1')
}
```

Comment: You effectively reset the value since you always set the key `name` every page load. You should check if there is already a value in storage before setting it to `ids` (since `ids` could be nonexistent).

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see a page demo, I believe you are navigating to a new URL after saving the search parameters to local storage.
This will cause your code to try to read 'id' from the URL again, but at this point, it isn't there anymore so it will store 'null' in localStorage this time.
Simply put, on the first run-through of your code it stores the correct id but when you change the URL it now stores `null`

The right way to do it will be to check if `ids`, which is the one from the URL, is `null` then:

- if it is, then read from localStorage
- if it isn't save it to localStorage, you can also move the code that hides the URL inside this scope so it only runs when you get a fresh ID

Edit:
Here is what I believe the code will look like:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const Urlparams =  new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const ids = Urlparams.get('id');
if(ids){
  localStorage.setItem("name", ids);
  // no need to wrap the pushState method in its own if clause 
  // since we're sure ids exists
  window.history.pushState('new','title','?m=1')
}else{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('name');
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you please share the codes... @Tochi

Comment: sure @Shira , but I would have no way of knowing it works for sure since I cannot test it

Comment: @Shira I just rewrote a bit of the code, but again, you will probably have to tweak it to work perfectly with the rest of your code